# Using an input box in MS Word to insert values into a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, inputbox

I am trying to put together what I had hoped would be a simple macro that would take a string of text with 4 different values that need to change between lines, but I am having a hard time getting the values to be added after the other text I have.

The basic goal of what I want to have spit out would be something like this,

1. Thence N88°08’26”E along the existing southerly property line of said grantor’s tract, a distance of 6.00 feet to a point, said point being 36.00 feet left of station 1002+30.19;

The Code I have currently is here,

```
Dim sSTA As Variant
sSTA = InputBox("STA")
Dim sOFF As Variant
sOFF = InputBox("OFF")
Dim sDist As Variant
sDist = InputBox("Dist")
Dim sBear As Variant
sBear = InputBox("Bear")



Selection.TypeText Text:= _
    "Thence "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="sBear"
Selection.TypeText Text:= _
    "continuing along the proposed temporary easement line, a distance of "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=sDist
Selection.TypeText Text:= _
    " feet to a point, said point being "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=sOFF
Selection.TypeText Text:= _
    " feet left of station "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=sSTA
Selection.TypeText Text:= _
    ";"
```

The output I keep getting ignores the user input from the input box.

Any tips on how to actually fix this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `sBear = InputBox("Bear")` etc simply captures the input as a string. So just do `"Thence " + sBear + " continuing etc"`

Comment: Multiple sequential input boxes are going to annoy your users. Consider using a UserForm to gather everything at once instead. http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm

Comment: Also, as an attorney who used to do abstracting, I know that there are relatively inexpensive programs too do metes and bounds descriptions and even draw them to make sure they close. Are you reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: I am fully agree with @CharlesKenyon that input boxes is not really a good idea to go. Ideally, I'd recommend creating an add-in with a task pane where users could enter their data.